# Use different wagtail page as root without slug

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, wagtail

I'm attempting to set a page as the root home page of my wagtail based site.

I know you can set the homepage using the `sites` setting. But, my use case is different.

I'm using a "redirect" page which redirects to an index page as the homepage. The index is restricted to only allow ertain page types (since it's an index....). But, this causes issues with other pages not being in the tree if it was set at the root.

Hence, the redirect. But, upon redirecting the `serve` view of the redirect page to use this page it picks up the slug.

I still want it to appear at the root url. Meaning, `/`. How can I achieve this?

High level description:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class IndexPage(Page):
     # children restricted to IndexSubpage

class IndexSubpage(Page):
     # parent restricted to IndexPage

class RedirectPage(Page):

     def serve(request):

           # Link is a link to a page through a ForeignKey....
          return redirect(self.link, permanent=True)
```

So, this will pick up the slug of `IndexPage` instead of being at `/`

Comment: Can you clarify if I understand correctly?
You want the URL `/` to always redirect to a slug `/my-custom-home-slug`
OR do you just want there to be no `/` URL, just a `/my-custom-home-slug`

Maybe it would be good to edit the question with the page tree you are hoping to achieve.

Comment: @LBBenJohnston Neither actually. My question is unclear, my apologies. Right now the RedirectPage redirects to the slug of the IndexPage. Which makes sense. But, in wagtail if the page is set as root it will also show without the slug (at the root of the domain so mydomain.com/ ) I' was trying to replicate this with the RedirectPage - i.e. redirecting to IndexPage but not appending the slug of IndexPage so it still shows as mydomain.com/. However, i just opened up the index to allow the static pages and set it as root to avoid the issue.